# Need Help Understanding Arrays in Methods - java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm a beginner at programming with little to no experience. I want to learn Java because I feel like it's such a great language to learn from. I've been following the guides on this playlist on youtube [here.](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFE2CE09D83EE3E28) If you look into it, I'm on the 32nd video and so far Java is very promising

Anyways, I need help understanding this code:

```
package learningjava;

class apples{
public static void main(String args[]){
    int lucas[]={3,4,5,6,7};
    change(lucas);
    
    for(int y: lucas)
        System.out.println(y);
}

public static void change(int x[]){
    for(int counter=0;counter<x.length;counter++){
        x[counter]+=5;
      }
   }
}
```

This code is supposed to take the array: `int lucas[]={3,4,5,6,7};` and add 5 to each number inside of the array. Then, it's supposed to display the sum of these numbers with 5 added to them; which it does just that, displays 8, 9 ,10,11,12. I just hope that someone could clear up the smoke for me on this one, cause it's hard to follow. I don't understand how array `lucas` is connected to `int x[]`. I also don't understand why we need the for loop or what it does.:

```
for(int counter=0;counter<x.length;counter++){
    x[counter]+=5;
}
```

This post was poorly made and explained, but I'm desperate at this point to know what exactly is going on in this code. If anyone could give me a thorough explanation, I would REALLY appreciate that!

Comment: The variable names are irrelevant.  You are passing a reference to lucas array into the change method, where it is called x.  That is still a reference to lucas.

Comment: Note: use `int[] lucas`, not `int lucas[]`. The `[]` is part of the type, not the variable name. The syntax is supported "as a nod to the tradition of C and C++", but discouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in the function *definition*

```
public static void change(int x[]){
```

`x` is a *formal* parameter - you may choose arbitrary name instead of `x`, as it is just placeholder for the `real` parameter.

Subsequent commands show what the function will perform with `real` parameter (so far unknown) *when the function will be called* by using formal parameter instead of real one.

Now the function is *called* (used):

```
change(lucas);
```

with the `real` parameter - yes we want change `lucas`! So the statements in the `change()` function *definition* are now performed with `lucas` instead of `x`.

---

Second: Why we need the loop

```
for(int counter=0;counter<x.length;counter++){
   x[counter]+=5;
}
```

In your particular code we *don't need the loop*, *nor the function `change()`*. We may use the *direct way* to add `5` to every element in the array:

```
lucas[0] += 5      // is it shortened form for lucas[0] = lucas[0] + 5
lucas[1] += 5
lucas[2] += 5
lucas[3] += 5
lucas[4] += 5
```

But we may meet generally 2 problems:

1. `lucas` may have *many* elements, not only `5`.
2. We want to do *the same thing* (adding 5 to each element) with *other* (so far not known) array, e. g. `mathew` - in future.

So we will solve both of these 2 problems generally - by defining the function `change()` which doesn´t know in advance the *name* of an array, nor the `number of its items`, nor the `values of its items`. Let `x` be the placeholder (formal parameter) for that array.

```
x.length
```

means *"use the attribute (property) length"* of that array - every array has this attribute an it is the number of its items.

So, after substituting the *real* parameter (`lucas` or `mathew`) for the *formal* one (`x`) we will know the numbers of items of this *real* array.

We use it in the `for` loop:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < x.length; counter++) {
```

Here is another placeholder (counter) and again - its name is not important, it may be other one, e. g. `i`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
```

We need this placeholder for indices (one index at a time) of array's element - they are numbered *not* from `1` but from `0`, so the 1st element has index `0`, 2nd `1`, etc. - so the last one will have index `x.length - 1`.

How to reach that this placeholder (`counter`, `i`, or other arbitrary name) will sequentially have values `0`, `1`, `2`, etc.?

The `for` statement

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < x.length; counter++) {
```

has `3 parts` in its header, delimited by `;`:

1. The 1st part defines what to do *initially*:
   `int counter = 0;    // set the first value of the placeholder to 0`
2. The 2nd part defines the *condition for continuation (of looping)*:
    `counter < x.length; // is the placeholder's value still less than number of items?`
   If this condition is not satisfied, the game for `for` loop is over.
3. The last part defines *what to do* (again and again):
   `counter++          // increase the counter's (placeholder) value`
   *after performing commands in the body of the loop* (between curly braces `{}`)

Now, in the body of the loop is just 1 statement

```
     x[counter] += 5;     // Shorter form for x[counter] = x[counter] + 5;
```

which will be performed *again and again by the previous rules* (of course, after substituting the *real* parameter (`lucas`) for the *formal* one (`x`)).

Answer (score 1):

In Java terms, the `int x[]` in your code is a method parameter/argument. When you call `change(lucas)` the `x` parameter points to the reference of `lucas` array. Now that its pointing to the `lucas` array, the for loop below

```
for(int counter=0;counter<x.length;counter++){
    x[counter]+=5;
}
```

iterates through the original `lucas` array and add the values.

Consider a scenario where the `x` points to a different reference/memory location inside the method and make the change, none of this would reflect in the actual `lucas' variable.

```
public static void change(int x[]){
    x = new int[]{3,4,5,6,7};
    for(int counter=0;counter<x.length;counter++){
        x[counter]+=5;
      }
   }
}
```

That's the key in understanding JAVA's pass-by-value & reference.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what is happening is the array initialization:

```
int lucas[]={3,4,5,6,7};
```

You are then calling the function `change()` and passing an array with the name `lucas` to it. The function `change()` is looping through each `int` in an array with the name `x` passed to it using a `counter` for the array index which starts at `0` and increments by `1` until it hits `x.length` which is `4` in this case. Every iteration it is taking the value of the int in this array and adding `5` to it.

P.S. Java is `Pass-By-Value`, but it acts similar to `Pass-By-Reference` when you pass an object - this is because you are passing the *reference* to the object by value. When you change the value in the array in the `change()` function, you are also changing the value at all other references to this array object.

Comment: Technically "everything in Java is Pass-By-Reference" is not true. I understand what you are referring here but I would suggest not to refer this as Pass-By-Reference.

Answer (score 0):

In order to read (print) the elements inside the array, we use loop, your lucas array consists of different numbers so in order to print your numbers inside the array, we use loop.